# How to filter out repeating HTML with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML I'm working on using programming from a CMS I didn't write and it's outputting some HTML radio options and is repeating them.  Unfortunately I can't control the output of this programming, so I'm attempting an alternative route of just trying to only allow 1 instance of the HTML to show up.  Here's an example:

```
<label class="fc_radio" for="shipping_service_101"><input type="radio" name="shipping_service" id="shipping_service_101" value="101|45" class="fc_radio fc_required"><span class="fc_shipping_carrier">USPS International Shipping Rate (tracking included)</span> <span class="fc_shipping_cost"><span class="fc_currency_symbol">$</span>45</span> </label>

<label class="fc_radio" for="shipping_service_101"><input type="radio" name="shipping_service" id="shipping_service_101" value="101|45" class="fc_radio fc_required"><span class="fc_shipping_carrier">USPS International Shipping Rate (tracking included)</span> <span class="fc_shipping_cost"><span class="fc_currency_symbol">$</span>45</span> </label>
```

As you can see, it's identical code.  Is there anyway with jQuery to essentially filter out the extra HTML that's being outputted and keep 1 instance of the HTML inside the ?  They're inside a div with this ID and Class:

```
<div id="fc_shipping_methods_inner" class="fc_shipping_methods_inner">
REPEATING HTML HERE
</div>
```

Comment: You should fix the problem or have the developers of the solution you are using fix it. Such a thing is a bug and you shouldnt be bandaging it with JS.

Comment: agreed.  having to hack in until can find a fix.  definitely not a long term solution, but one for now nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just one extra element, you can do this:

`$('label.fc_radio').eq(1).remove();`

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZgLaU/

If it is more than one element, use `.slice()`

`$('label.fc_radio').slice(1).remove();`

**Example 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZgLaU/1/

Comment: OP did NOT mention that there will be two duplicated items at most. It should be something like $('label.fc_radio:gt(0)').remove();

Comment: Agreed @Kai.  That's why I gave the second option.  Check the HTML in that fiddle.  There are six inputs.  The code removes all but the first one.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var uniqueRadioIDs  = [];

$('#fc_shipping_methods_inner label.fc_radio').each(function() {
  if(uniqueRadioIDs.indexOf($(this).attr('for')) == -1) {
    // unknown yet, add to list
    uniqueRadioIDs.push($(this).attr('for'));
  } 
  else
  {
    // duplicate
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: hey sled, thanks for the code.  just gave it a spin but it's not working: http://jsfiddle.net/flinx777/xmQuD/ ... any ideas?

Comment: hi, seems like jsfiddle is broken at the moment. A simple hello world fails too ;) Besides you need to wrap the code like: `$(document).ready(function() { /* code goes here */ });`